# How to get the content of the tinymc text editor so that it can be passed with a form

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, tinymce

I'm new with TinyMc and I'm trying to add an editor to my Laravel project. I've been able to get it working so far, but I don't know how to get the content of the editor and pass it to the controller so it can be saved on the database.
This is the code of the editor:

```
<div>
    <form action="{{ route('page.update', ['id' => $text->id]) }}" method="post">

        @csrf
        <textarea id="contenuto">{{$text->Contenuto}}</textarea>
        <label for="mySubmit" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="bi-check-lg"></i> Save</label>
        <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="hidden" />
        
    </form>
</div>
```

If I submit this, the section with id="contenuto" results as empty.

I need the form to pass the content of the editor to the controller so it can be saved to the database. The content is simple text with no images

**Update**

The request gives me an error *"Attempt to assign property "Contenuto" on null"*

The code of my editor is

```html
<div>
    <form action="{{ route('page.update', ['id' => $text->id]) }}" method="post">

        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea id="contenuto" name="Contenuto">{{$text->Contenuto}}</textarea>
        </div>

        <label for="mySubmit" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="bi-check-lg"></i> Save</label>
        <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="hidden" />

    </form>
</div>
```

and the code in the DataLayer.php file is

```html
public function pageStore($id, $contenuto) {
        $dl = new DataLayer();
        $text = $dl -> getTextByID($id);
        $text->Contenuto = $contenuto;
        $text->save();
        // massive update (only with fillable property enabled on Author): 
        // Author::find($id)->update(['firstname' => $first_name, 'lastname' => $last_name]);
    }

    public function getTextByID($id)
    {
        ##$texts = Text::where('text_id', $text_id)->get();
        ##return $texts[0];

        return Text::find($id);
    }
```

Comment: Your textarea needs a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When submitting a form with HTML alone (not javascript), it's the field `name` attribute that is needed during submission.

```
<div>
    <form action="{{ route('page.update', ['id' => $text->id]) }}" method="post">

        @csrf
        <textarea id="contenuto" name="contenuto">{{$text->Contenuto}}</textarea>
        <label for="mySubmit" class="btn btn-dark"><i class="bi-check-lg"></i> Save</label>
        <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="hidden" />
        
    </form>
</div>
```